# Reading of the value between HTML tags into C# winform application

Tags: c#, html, browser

I am trying to read a value from a twitter page.The page source looks like this

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
    <title>Twitter / Authorize an application</title>

  ...........

    <div id="bd" role="main">

<p class="action-information">You've granted access to yourapp!</p>

<div id="oauth_pin">
  <p>
    <span id="code-desc">Next, return to yourapp and enter this PIN to complete the authorization process:</span>
    <kbd aria-labelledby="code-desc"><code>58643144</code></kbd>
  </p>
</div>


    </div>

   ..............

  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the value of 'PIN' into my C# winform application.Means,the value between code tags in the below line

```
<kbd aria-labelledby="code-desc"><code>58643144</code></kbd>
```

I have tried the below code.But this is not working because the PIN is enclosed in div tags and don't have an id. please help to get the value of PIN from the html web page. Thanks

```
string verifier = browser.TextField(Find.ById("code-desc")).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

why not try some kind of HTML parser and prase for value inside specific tag in your case code

here is a link to a good html parser that can be used for c# apps.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

```
StringBuilder codew = new StringBuilder();
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlTextNode node in
      doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//code/text()"))
{
    codew.Append(node.Text.Trim());
}
string foundcode = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi,thanks..But,using htmlagilitypack also ,I am not able to read the partcular node. I have tried the following.
 var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
           var document = webGet.Load(uri.ToString());
           HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='oauth_pin']");

   But the nodes is null. How can take the pin value ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string verifier = browser.TextField(Find.ById("code-desc")).Text
```

instead of

```
string verifier = browser.TextField(Find.ById("code-desc")).Value
```

Comment: It will not work.browser is not able to do Find.ById("code-desc").then how Text and Value will make a difference.